# Why the default constructor isn't called?

Tags: c++

I want to pass class name `oltosmol` as an argument so it will create an object with default constructor. It would normally work but not here. And the problem is only with `oltosmol`.

```
error: request for member 'creator' in 'smolifier', which is of non-class type 'StatP::CharProcessor\<StatP::oltosmol\>(StatP::oltosmol)'
```

```
namespace StatP
{
    class oltosmol
    {
    public:
        oltosmol() {}
        char transform(char c)
        {
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                return c + 'a' - 'A';
            return c;
        }
    };
    class Cutifier
    {
        unsigned period;
        unsigned counter;
    public:
        Cutifier(unsigned p): period(p), counter(0) {}
        char transform(char c)
        {
            if (counter == period)
            {
                counter = 0;

                if (c == ' ')
                    return '\3';
                else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                    return c - 'a' + 'A';
                else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                    return c - 'A' + 'a';
                return c;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                return c;
            }
        }
    };

    template<class Transformer>
    class CharProcessor
    {
        Transformer transformer;
    public:
        CharProcessor(const Transformer &t): transformer(t) {}

        String<char> creator(String<char> &s)
        {
            char *n_data = new char[s.get_length() + 1];
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.get_length(); i++)
                n_data[i] = transformer.transform(s[i]);
            n_data[s.get_length()] = '\0';

            return String<char>(n_data);
        }
        void changer(String<char> &s)
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.get_length(); i++)
                s[i] = transformer.transform(s[i]);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    const char coca_cola[] = "Coca-cola";

    String<char> water_name = coca_cola;
    copy = water_name;

//    ...


    StatP::CharProcessor<StatP::oltosmol> smolifier(StatP::oltosmol);
    std::cout << smolifier.creator(water_name) << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to add `()` and remove namespace, but it's still doesn't work. The program would run, if I firstly assign object to a variable, but I don't want and shouldn't do that.

Comment: `StatP::oltosmol` is a class, a type. Because you attempt to pass it as an argument, the symbol `smolifier` is really a function declaration. It declares a function that takes a `StatP::oltosmol` objects by value as argument, and return a `StatP::CharProcessor<StatP::oltosmol>` object by value. You need to pass an actual `StatP::oltosmol` object to the `CharProcessor` constructor.

Comment: But right after this attempt to create `smolifier` I create  `StatP::CharProcessor<StatP::Cutifier> cutifier(StatP::Cutifier(0))`, where i also pass class name as an argument, but with a difference that I clearly want to call argument constructor. Isn't `Class_name` passed as an argument should just call default constructor?

Comment: `StatP::Cutifier` is a class, a type. `StatP::Cutifier(0)` is an actual expression that results in an actual object of the type `StatP::Cutifier`.

Comment: If you want to create a default-constructed `StatP::oltosmol` object, then use e.g. `StatP::oltosmol{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your instantiation of `smolifier` you have to pass an instantiated object. Writing a type in the argument list is invalid syntax.

This is what you need there:

```
StatP::CharProcessor smolifier(StatP::oltosmol{});
```

Observe that due to CTAD, you don't actually have to spell out the type argument to the class template because it can be inferred from the constructor argument.

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hbeaEd3P3), with some types replaced because you didn't provide them)

Comment: Note that CTAD is C++17 feature, which isn't mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

This constructor passes pointer to a function which is not a thing you intend to pass:

```cpp
... smolifier(StatP::oltosmol)
```

To do the thing you intended you require instantiate your class and than pass it to the `CharProcessor`:

```cpp
StatP::oltosmol smol{};
... smolifier(smol);
```

But in your case better solution to remove reference from constructor and pass it by value and move it inside `CharProcessor` completely;

```cpp
CharProcessor(Transformer t): transformer(std::move(t)) {}
...
// And now you can just put braces
CharProcessor<oltsmol> smolifer({});
```